# How to draw a triangle with knowing the length of 3 heights only????

Tags: geometry

I tried it,then I found that the product of the two parts of same height will be equal to the other 2 products getting in the same way,Then I tried to do it by drawing it as the bisecting chords of a circle,the product will be same,but not getting the triangle,Pls help me!!!!!!!!

Comment: $3$ heights? do you mean length of $3$ sides?

Comment: Length of 3 heights

Comment: Find the reciprocal of each height, then make a triangle out of the reciprocals.

Comment: Then what?????,Why do we take reciprocals of heights,Can you pls explain it.I am a 10th standard student,pls don't use complicated terms.

Comment: The product of each height and its side is twice the area of the triangle.  So if the heights are h,j,k, then the sides are 2A/h,2A/j and 2A/k.

Comment: Thanks,I will try to make out more facts from it.Anyway ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK let's define some variables first. Let $[ABC]$ be the area of the triangle, and $h_A,$ $h_B,$ and $h_C$ be the heights, respectively. Also, define $a,$ $b,$ and $c$ to be the lengths of segments $AB,$ $AC,$ and $BC,$ respectively.

Note that, trivially, $a=\frac{2[ABC]}{h_a},$ and so on. Therefore, the sides must be in the form $\frac{2[ABC]}{h_a},\frac{2[ABC]}{h_b},\frac{2[ABC]}{h_c}.$